# What do I need to create a RESTful API Server in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, architecture

I would like to build my own RESTful API Server and I have no idea what I need for that.

I'll tell you a bit about the project:

On a Webservice (www.mysite.com/) users can register and manage their account and so on. But they also can use the RESTful API (mysite.com/api/...) and can do there pretty much the same via REST.

What is a good way to realize that? Do I need to use jetty or something similar?
Should I split web service and restful api ? what I a good architecture for that?

Thanks :)

Comment: This question is now 3 years old. Today I would use Dropwizard.

Comment: This question is now 5 years old. Today I use Spring Boot and Dropwizard.

Comment: Consider using AWS Beanstalk.

Comment: @RobAnderson what are you using this year?

Comment: @AmitSingh I tested and liked quarkus. Its is super fast and lightweight. However not all libraries are compatible. IMO the industry is mostly using Spring Boot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Spring controller for building a restful server. You can run it on tomcat or jetty doesn't matter.

Check this url : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html

Answer (score 4):

Tomcat and Jersey are easy to get up and running. I've had some issues with Tomcat 7 and Jersey, but with Tomcat 6 it was straight forward.

This [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html) is quite easy to follow. It's a bit old, but the principle remains the same.

Comment: the link is already shared by @Gertjan Assies in the above answers

Comment: Yes, we overlapped by a few minutes. I guess I missed the other answer while looking for one myself.

Answer (score 3):

IBM provides good set of information and tutorials about building RESTful web service with Java ([Link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/training/kp/j-kp-rest/index.html)). After getting your web service running, you can deploy it to Amazon. Take a look at [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).

Answer (score 3):

In 2017 one of the best solutions would be to use [spring boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/). Gives you great effects without writing tons of code.

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple example at http://coder2design.com/rest-web-services/
to build a REST application.

- XML Schema(xsd) is used to build domain classes.
- Eclipse EE is used as IDE and Maven for building.
- Jersey as a framework for REST
- Hibernate for persistence layer.
- MySQL as DB

All other configurations are nicely explained.

Comment: Overkill if you just want to make small to medium size apps